# When i run the flask app i get this error

Tags: python, flask

i am in the flask directory that i made

C:\Users\Saad Mohammed>cd C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\flask_app

C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\flask_app>set FLASK_APP=sample_app.ipynb

C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\flask_app>flask run

and i still get this error

- Serving Flask app 'sample_app.ipynb' (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
  Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
  Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'sample_app.ipynb'.

when i change my file name from sample_app.ipynb to sample_app.py and try to do flask run i get this error

C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\flask_app>flask run

- Serving Flask app 'sample_app' (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
  Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

File "c:\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Python\Python39\Scripts\flask.exe_*main*_.py", line 7, in

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 994, in main
cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 600, in main
return super().main(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 849, in run_command
app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 324, in __init__self._load_unlocked()

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 350, in _load_unlocked self._app = rv = self.loader()

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 406, in load_app app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)

File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 260, in locate_app **import**(module_name)

File "C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\flask_app\sample_app.py", line 37, in 
"execution_count": null,

NameError: name 'null' is not defined

how do i remove these errors

Comment: Could you try formatting this question and putting any output text inside of code blocks? It's currently hard to read and understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

**Flask run** command work with python scripts(.py), not with jupyter notebooks(.ipynb). So you can rewrite your code from 'sample_app.ipynb' to 'sample_app.py' file.
For example sample_app.py should contain following code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if you pay attention to the contents of the ipynb file, you will see that a json-like format is used there to store the order of calculations.
For example the same code in jupyter notebook format(.ipynb).

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "from flask import Flask\n",
    "app = Flask(__name__)\n",
    "\n",
    "\n",
    "@app.route('/')\n",
    "def index():\n",
    "    return \"<h1>Hello, World!</h1>\"\n",
    "\n",
    "if __name__ == '__main__':\n",
    "    app.run(debug=True)\n",
    "\n",
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python"
  },
  "orig_nbformat": 4
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

That means we need to create new file sample_app.py in code editor and **write code from scratch**.
After that specify environment variable FLASK_APP to just 'sample_app' without .py.

```
export FLASK_APP=sample_app
```

And finally get running server.

```
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "sample_app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

have a nice coding!

Comment: i renamed my file from 'sample_app.ipynb' to 'sample_app.py' and then i tried running

Comment: You need to create new file sample_app.py in code editor and write code from scratch, not rename jupyter notebook file

Comment: also is there a method to run this on jupyter notebook itself without using code editor cause i am watch this deep learning course videos made by deeplizard and there they were running that block code directly through jupyter notebook

Comment: never mind i got it instead of opening a notebook i just had to open a text file in jupyter notebook and then save it as <file_name>.py and run those commands on command prompt